# Booting Ubuntu on a Windows machine

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm all entirely new to this. I'm hoping to convert from Windows to some flavour of Linux - here' what happens when I try:-

I downloaded a Ubuntu iso image and burnt it to a DVD. When I boot from it:-

1. Two little icons appear at the bottom of the screen (man + keyboard?)
2. After several minutes I temporarily get a pure-grey screen plus responsive mouse-pointer
   3 After a while longer the screen goes black, then briefly flashes a slightly lighter shade of black (!) and the mouse pointer appears. Then it goes black again. This sequence repeats for about 10 minutes after which I give up and go and make a cup of tea instead.

I have repeated the above but loading the iso image to a USB stick. The identical sequence occurs.

I assume the overall boot sequence should not take the 15 minutes I've allowed so far, so I have a problem. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

My computer runs XP/SP3 with 1.25GB ram and at least 8GB disc space spare on each of its 3 disc drives.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to install ubuntu.
option 1: Install through booting iso image
option 2: install ubuntu inside windows.

Since you are new to this, I would suggest you to install ubuntu inside windows which is option #2. It is very easy to install and remove when you dont need it. Please follow the below steps.

1. Boot the system using windows.
2. Once windows started completely, then insert DVD/CD/USB which contains ubunutu ISO image.
3. It request you to run like normal application install.
4. Choose "Install inside ubunutu"
   then follow the instruction according to your preference.

Hope this helps.